# Can R read.csv return an empty data frame?

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a project where I am iterating through thousands of text files and reading these into a large data frame. I was able to get all of the files into a list named `filenames`. The loop looks something like this:

```
for(i in 1:length(filenames))
{
   text <- read.csv(filenames[i], header = T)
   //Analysis on text
}
```

Unfortunately, several of the text files are completely empty (too many to manually delete). Read.csv throws an error when it encounters one of these files, and the for loop terminates. Is there any way that I can get around this error by having read.csv return an empty data frame instead of an error? Thanks.

Comment: Also, with thousands of files you could look into using `lapply()` and a faster function for reading text files (e.g., `data.table::fread()` or `readr::read_csv()`. Up to you! It looks like `readr::read_csv()` will just have an empty dataframe in R with no errors thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can instead put the instruction in `try`  and the loop will continue.
Code:

```
 for(i in 1:length(filenames))
  {
   try(
    text <- read.csv(filenames[i], header = T)
    //Analysis on text
      )
  }
```